# Simple jquery slide element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, height

I'm totally new in js and jq. I'am trying force my #cont div to change height on hover with animation and back to previous height without hover, but I dont know how to achieve that. In my test it should make an alert (or make other function), right?

http://jsfiddle.net/JJh9z/1773/

```
<div id='cont'>
    <ul>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
        <li>an item</li>
    </ul>
    <div id='ruch'>HOVER</div>
</div>

#cont {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

#ruch {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}

var result = $("#cont").height();

$('#ruch').hover(function(){
    $('#cont').animate({height:'300px'}, 500);
});

if (result == 300) {
    alert(result)
}
```

Comment: Any reason for the old version of jQuery? Also, `.hover()` usually expects two functions.

Comment: any reason you are using `hover` instead of a `click` event?

Comment: Here's a fiddle changing the size with jQuery and CSS - you could transition the size with CSS slower if you were so inclined - http://jsfiddle.net/JJh9z/1780/

Answer (score 0):

Your if statement only runs once when the script is first loaded, so no it won't alert each time someone hovers. it is not an event listener.

You need to add another event listener for when the mouse leaves the element (mouseout). See this modified code:

```
$('#ruch').hover(function(){
    $('#cont').animate({height:'300px'}, 500);
});

$('#ruch').mouseout(function(){
    $('#cont').animate({height:'200px'}, 500);

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JJh9z/1775/

Comment: You may have issues with this version because `#ruch` moves from under the mouse and activate mouseleave/mouseout.

Comment: If it worked for you could you vote up/pick as the correct answer thx

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

You can specify a handleout event handler, in which you'd restore the element to its previous height.
You also should select not the 'HOVER' div (it's small) but a bigger element (like cont):

```
$('#cont').hover(

function () {
    $('#cont').animate({
        height: '300px'
    }, 500);
},

function () {
    $('#cont').animate({
        height: '200px'
    }, 500);
});
```

Here, I've specified a hover-out handler, and focused on 'cont' instead of 'ruch'

http://jsfiddle.net/JJh9z/1773/

Comment: But for me its important to get HOVER (for ex) as hover element in my bigger div, because it will be jpg element, and background of #cont will repeat-y

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/JJh9z/1784/). As you can see, if you apply the event handlers to 'HOVER', the mouse will be outside of the hover div when the div moves. Up to you how you want to set it up..

Answer (score 0):

To prevent multiple animations for one hover event since `#ruch` moves from under the mouse pointer during hover animation, use the following and a current version of jQuery:

```
var result = $("#cont").height();

$('#ruch').on( 'mouseenter', function(){
    $('#cont').animate({height:'300px'}, 500, function() {
       alert( result );
    });
});

$('#cont').on( 'mouseleave', function(){
    if( $(this).height() != result ) {
       $(this).animate({height:result}, 500);
    }
});
```

Once the `#cont` expands the mouse is no longer over `#ruch` and any slight movement would fire `mouseleave` and the `#cont` collapses. To prevent that, attach the `mouseleave` event to `#cont` as above.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this. One is to call the 'after animation completes function'. which takes another function as option.. the below example alerts 'Hii' after animating the height to 300px.

```
$( "#ruch").hover(function() {
  $( "#cont" ).animate({
    height: "300px"
  }, {
    duration: 500,
    complete: function() {
      alert('Hii');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could play around with some webkit transitions as well, which is pretty easy.

The problem with adding an event listener for when the mouse leaves the even and queuing up an animation is that you can end up with a queue of many animations if you move your mouse crazily over the div, while this method will only do one animation.

```
#cont {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
}

#ruch {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
}

$(document).on('mouseover', '#cont', function() {
    document.getElementById('cont').style.height = 300;
});

$(document).on('mouseleave', '#cont', function() {
   document.getElementById('cont').style.height = 200;
});
```